# Django Celery Beat, change app name in admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-celery

When we create our custom apps we can assign `verbose_name` in `myproject/myapp/apps.py`:

```
class MainConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'main'
    verbose_name = 'My Own Verbose Name'
```

I have added `django_celery_beat` into my `INSTALLED_APPS` and now my admin page has this app:

[image: Admin Page]

How I can change this `Periodic Tasks` app name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer to my own question.

The only way of changing the name of app of django_celery_beat that I have found is to use translation:

msgid "Periodic Tasks"
   msgstr "My Own Name for this App"

Answer (score 4):

You can change without translation by the next way:

```py
from django_celery_beat.apps import BeatConfig
BeatConfig.verbose_name = "My Own Name for this App"
```